How to use a HuggingFace Tokenizer with SparkNLP Pipeline?
I want to use a NER model from HF hub in Spark NLP. I have followed the tutorial https://colab.research.google.com/github/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/blob/master/examples/python/transformers/HuggingFace%20in%20Spark%20NLP%20-%20DistilBertForTokenClassification.ipynb#scrollTo=C_hLrg6RA3UT. However for specific examples it does not give the same results. For example in Python the string 100-Bank of America gives as ORG, however in SparkNLP, it gives LOC. It happens because the Tokenization, as SparkNLP uses it own true tokenizer (Tokenizer()).
Here the example
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification

from transformers import pipeline

MODEL_NAME = "elastic/distilbert-base-cased-finetuned-conll03-english"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

nlp = pipeline("ner", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

example = "100-Bank of America"

ner_results = nlp(example)

The results are
[{'entity': 'B-ORG', 'score': 0.9992428, 'index': 3, 'word': 'Bank', 'start': 4, 'end': 8}, {'entity': 'I-ORG', 'score': 0.99944407, 'index': 4, 'word': 'of', 'start': 9, 'end': 11}, {'entity': 'I-ORG', 'score': 0.99941075, 'index': 5, 'word': 'America', 'start': 12, 'end': 19}]

However the same model converted to Spark using SparkNLP gives the following result (following exactly the notebook mentioned above)

It is not able to separate 100- from Bank and the only chunk detected is America and it classifies as LOC
To use the Tokenizer from HF within SparkNLP, I did a CustomTranformer to use as PreProcessing where I load the tokenizer from HF and use if before the DocumentAssembler
from sparknlp.annotator import *
# from sparknlp_jsl.annotator import *
from sparknlp.base import *
from sparknlp.functions import *
from sparknlp.annotation import Annotation

from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Param, Params
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

from transformers import TFDistilBertForTokenClassification, DistilBertTokenizer

MODEL_NAME = 'elastic/distilbert-base-cased-finetuned-conll03-english'

HFTokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

#custom transformer
class HuggingFaceTokenizer(Transformer,
                      HasInputCol,
                      HasOutputCol,
                      DefaultParamsReadable,
                      DefaultParamsWritable):

    value = Param(
        Params._dummy(),
        "value",
        "value to fill",
    )


    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self,):
        super(HuggingFaceTokenizer, self).__init__()
        self._setDefault(value=None)
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self._set(**kwargs)

    def setInputCol(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`inputCol`.
        """
        self.input_col_name = value
        return self._set(inputCol=value)

    def setOutputCol(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`outputCol`.
        """
        self.output_col_name = value
        return self._set(outputCol=value)

    def setHFTokenizer(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`outputCol`.
        """
        self.tokenizer_hf = value
        return self._set(value=value)

    def _transform(self, dataset):

        def tokenize_text(text):
            text_tokenized = self.tokenizer_hf.tokenize(text)
            return ' '.join(text_tokenized)

        udf_hf_tokenizer = F.udf(tokenize_text, StringType())
        dataset = dataset.withColumn(self.output_col_name, udf_hf_tokenizer(dataset[self.input_col_name]))
        return dataset


hftokenizer = HuggingFaceTokenizer()\
                  .setInputCol("text")\
                  .setOutputCol("text")\
                  .setHFTokenizer(HFTokenizer)

documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler()\
                    .setInputCol("text")\
                    .setOutputCol("document")

sentenceDetector = SentenceDetector() \
    .setInputCols(["document"]) \
    .setOutputCol("sentence")

regexTokenizer = Tokenizer() \
    .setInputCols(["sentence"]) \
    .setOutputCol("token")

model = (
    DistilBertForTokenClassification.load("xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/model_spark_nlp")
    .setInputCols(["sentence",'token'])
    .setOutputCol("pos")
)


converter = (
        NerConverter()
        .setInputCols(["document", "token", "pos"])
        .setOutputCol("tag")
    )

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[
                            hftokenizer,
                            documentAssembler,
                            sentenceDetector,
                            regexTokenizer,
                            model,
                            converter
                            ])

This pipeline works perfectly, however when I try to save it, it returns an error
MODEL_OUTPUT_PATH = f'{MODEL_NAME}_sparknlp_pipeline'
pipeline.write().overwrite().save(MODEL_OUTPUT_PATH)


Object of type DistilBertTokenizer is not JSON serializable

1 - Is there an easy way to use a DistilBert Tokenizer within SparkNLP?
2 - If the answer for the first question is no, what can I do to make my solution to work?
P.S. I have started a conversation in GitHUB about it, however it is still unclear what I can do to solve my issue github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/discussions/14235
Cheers
